# Domain Profile to Local Profile

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-xp, windows-7

What is the best method for migrating a domain profile to a local profile. We're swapping from a domain to just a workgroup. We have some XP machines and Windows 7 machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done this on Windows 7, but I just used this guide to convert Windows XP laptops from a domain to a workgroup.

http://msmvps.com/blogs/clustering/archive/2004/10/06/15096.aspx

Print it out before you start making the changes...

Comment: Alright but any ideas on Windows 7? I believe it's quite a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the [User Profile Wizard](http://www.forensit.com/downloads.html) from ForensIT. I know it works for associating an existing local profile with a domain user account; not sure if it works the other way.

When selecting the domain to join, enter the hostname of the local PC.